# Rollback to savepoint doesn't release locks

Tags: sql, transactions, commit, rollback, savepoints

I think I have a misunderstanding about how to use Savepoints. Perhaps someone can clear it up for me. I present my example as what I am trying to do, and what I have experienced.

My app is doing a certain procedure.
Before that procedure (and associated DB operations) I create a savepoint.
During that procedure, I initiate a select for update,
which creates a number of locks:

lock1 - duration=transaction, class=row, type=intent row=big number

lock2 - duration=transaction, class=row, type=WriteNoPK row=big number

Should that java procedure succeed, the associated DB transaction is completed via a commit.
However, if the java procedure fails, I want also to rollback any associated DB operations.
I have been attempting this by:

conn.rollback(mySavepoint);

However, this has not been releasing the table locks created (above) by the DB operations (that I thought I just rolled back by conn.rollback(mySavepoint);)

I have tested this behaviour with two databases:  Sybase, and Derby.

Why is this the case?

Do I really need to commit after the conn.rollback(mySavepoint)   ???
It just seems a bit counter-intuitive.